# Azure CLI: delete all untagged images within a repository in one command

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-container-registry

I am storing my docker images in a private repository on Azure. Everytime I push an image to that repository with the same tag (e.g., latest), the previous image becomes untagged, but remains in the repository. This has led to stacking a lot of untagged images, in the repository. I would like a command, using the azure cli, to delete all the untagged images in just one go.

For instance, typing the following command:

`az acr repository show-manifests -n myRegistry --repository myRepo`

returned several manifests for the  d24-staging-fuzzy-search-srv repository:

`[
  {
    "digest": "sha256:blablabla1",
    "tags": null,
    "timestamp": "t1"
  },
  {
    "digest": "sha256:blablabla2",
    "tags": null,
    "timestamp": "t2"
  },
  {
    "digest": "sha256:blablabla3",
    "tags": [
      "latest"
    ],
    "timestamp": "t3"
  }]`

I would like to have a command in azure cli that deletes all the mainfests that have a tag of "null" and keep the one that has the tag "latest"

Comment: It was not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

In case someone is still wondering what is the one liner command to accomplish this, please use the following Bash Script:

`az acr repository show-manifests -n <registryName> --repository <repositoryName> --query "[?tags[0]==null].digest" -o tsv  | xargs -I% az acr repository delete -n <registryName> -t <repositoryName>@% -y`

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-faq

Header: How do I delete all manifests that are not referenced by any tag in a repository?

Comment: This removes too many manifests when using buildx: only the platform-agnostic-manifest has a tag. This command removes the actual image and leaves the tag unusable.

Answer (score 2):

**For Linux bash**

`az acr repository show-manifests -n myRegistry --repository myRepository --query "[?tags[0]==null].digest" -o tsv  | xargs -I% az acr repository delete -n myRegistry -t myRepository@% --yes`

**For Windows PowerShell:**

`az acr repository show-manifests -n myRegistry --repository myRepository --query "[?tags[0]==null].digest" -o tsv | %{ az acr repository delete -n myRegistry -t myRepository@$_  --yes }`

Comment: The `repository show-manifests` command is apparently being deprecated. I found this to work as a replacement:  
`az acr manifest list-metadata -r myRegistry -n myRepository --query "[?tags[0]==null].digest" -o tsv | xargs -I% az acr repository delete -n myRegistry -t myRepository% --yes`

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the command below.

```
az acr repository delete -n yourRegistry --image yourRepo:null
```

For more details, refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/acr/repository?view=azure-cli-latest#examples).

> Delete an image by tag. This deletes the manifest referenced by 'hello-world:latest', all other tags referencing the manifest, and any associated layer data.
>
> `az acr repository delete -n MyRegistry --image hello-world:latest`

Answer (score -1):

I ended up creating a node script, in which I injected azure cli commands using shelljs.

Basically what I did is, For each repository, I fetched all its manifests, and for each manifests that does not contain the label "latest" was deleted